# What did I do wrong in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table divorced_females 
select cust_id, cust_first_name,cust_last_name, cust_gender, cust_marital_status from customers 
where cust_gender = 'F' and cust_marital_status = 'divorced';
```

I am getting errors like below:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>   create table divorced_females
>   select cust_id, cust_first_name,cust_last_name, cust_gender,  cust_marital_status from customers
>   where cust_gender = 'F' and cust_marital_status = 'divorced'
>
> Error report
>   ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
>   00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where you trying to create a table from the result of a `select` statement? Such a statement is called a CTAS statement ("Create Table As Select ...")  You are missing the keyword **`AS`** between the table name and the keyword `select`.

Answer (score 2):

You missing 'AS' after table name.

Try statement below:

```
create table divorced_females as
select cust_id, cust_first_name,cust_last_name, cust_gender, cust_marital_status 
from customers 
where cust_gender = 'F' and cust_marital_status = 'divorced';
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the CREATE TABLE AS statement copying the selected columns is:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT column_1, column2, ... column_n
  FROM old_table);
```

So in your case query will be

```
create table divorced_females  AS 
 (select cust_id, cust_first_name,cust_last_name, cust_gender, cust_marital_status 
 from customers 
where cust_gender = 'F' and cust_marital_status = 'divorced');
```